# How effectively load the vertical line datas from memory into neon registers

Tags: load, arm, neon

I want to read a vertical line of data from an image block, ie: I want to get the first data of every line (line length equal the block width).

I think the following code is not good. Is there a better implementation?
(the data address in r5, the line length in r1)

```
vld1.u8     d3[0],  [r5],   r1
vld1.u8     d3[1],  [r5],   r1
vld1.u8     d3[2],  [r5],   r1
vld1.u8     d3[3],  [r5],   r1
vld1.u8     d3[4],  [r5],   r1
vld1.u8     d3[5],  [r5],   r1
vld1.u8     d3[6],  [r5],   r1
vld1.u8     d3[7],  [r5],   r1
vld1.u8     d4[0],  [r5],   r1
vld1.u8     d5[0],  [r5],   r1
vld1.u8     d5[1],  [r5],   r1    
vld1.u8     d5[2],  [r5],   r1
vld1.u8     d5[3],  [r5],   r1   
vld1.u8     d5[4],  [r5],   r1
vld1.u8     d5[5],  [r5],   r1    
vld1.u8     d5[6],  [r5],   r1
vld1.u8     d5[7],  [r5],   r1
```

Comment: If you're going to do this for every column in the image you might want to transpose the whole image first.

Comment: Thanks,Paul. The above code just one step of our post-processing, so i do not think transpose the whole image is necessary. Do you have any other optimized methods of this kind of loading

Comment: It really depends on how many column-wise operations you need to do and whether they can be grouped together. It is often the case though with SIMD code that transposing the image first (or transposing blocks of it) can be more efficient than paying the penalty of non-contiguous loads in your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NEON only directly support non-continous loads for strides up to 4 (Via the VLDn instructions where n is the stride size). Since you're line length is presumably much larger than that, I don't see a way to do what you want apart from loading each element individually like your code code does.

However, if you need to apply this post-processing step *not* only to the first column, but to all columns, then you could process 8 (or 16, if you use Q registers) columns at once, instead of processing them individually. How feasable that is depends on your algorithm, of course.

Ideally, you'd crank up the chunk size even further, and process ss many columns at once as fit into one cache line (64 on most ARMs, if your element size is 8 bit). Otherwise, if your image has lots of rows, the cache lines containing the first rows will have been removed from the cache by the time you've processed the last ones, and they'll have to be re-fetched to process the next chunk of columns.